Terminal Loading bar not updating correctly
I'm building a Multilevel Feedback Queue Scheduling(MLFQ) sorting Algorithm simulation and I'm having the results of each process print out to the terminal and they each have a loading bar and I need them to update accordingly. Right now I can get the loading bar to update correctly
This is what it looks like when it is printing:
Timestamp Process ID
===============     ] ========            ]          [8]   Process  9 [    [5]   Process  6 [  4 [
It is not having each process on its own separate line and its not updating correctly. Is the problem that I'm using threads? Any help would be appreciated
//.h file
 #pragma once
 #ifndef MLFQ_H
 #define MLFQ_H

#include <vector>

struct Process {
    int processID;
    int arrivalTime;
    int burstTime;
    int priority;

    Process(int id, int arrival, int burst, int prio) :
        processID(id), arrivalTime(arrival), burstTime(burst), priority(prio) {}
};

class MLFQ {
private:
    std::vector<Process> processes;
    std::vector<Process> queue0; // Highest priority
    std::vector<Process> queue1; // Medium priority
    std::vector<Process> queue2; // Lowest priority

 public:
    MLFQ(std::vector<Process>& procs);
    void runMLFQ();
 };


#endif

//.cpp file
#include "MLFQ.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

// Mutex for ensuring thread-safe access to cout
std::mutex coutMutex;

// Named constants
const int MAX_PROCESS_ID_WIDTH = 10;
const int MAX_TIMESTAMP_LENGTH = 10;
const int LOADING_BAR_WIDTH = 20;

// Helper function to print column headers
void printColumnHeaders() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);
    std::cout << "\033[1;34m" << std::right << std::setw(MAX_TIMESTAMP_LENGTH) << "Timestamp "
        << std::left << std::setw(MAX_PROCESS_ID_WIDTH) << "Process ID" << std::endl;
}

// Helper function to print process message
void printProcessMessage(const Process& process, int currentTime) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);
    std::cout << "\033[1;33m" << std::right << std::setw(MAX_TIMESTAMP_LENGTH) << "[" << currentTime << "] "
        << std::right << std::setw(MAX_PROCESS_ID_WIDTH) << "Process " << std::setw(2) << process.processID << " [";
}

// Helper function to print loading bar
void printLoadingBar(int progress) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < LOADING_BAR_WIDTH; ++i) {
        if (i < progress) {
            std::cout << "=";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "] ";
    std::cout << std::flush;
}

// Helper function to execute process
void executeProcess(const Process& process, int& currentTime) {
    // Print process ID
    printProcessMessage(process, currentTime);

    // Simulate processing time
    for (int i = 0; i < process.burstTime; ++i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        ++currentTime;
        // Print execution progress
        int progress = LOADING_BAR_WIDTH * (i + 1) / process.burstTime;
        std::cout << "\r"; // Move cursor to the beginning of the line
        printLoadingBar(progress);
        std::cout << std::flush; // Flush the output buffer
    }

    std::cout << "\033[K\033[0m" << std::endl; // Clear the line and reset color
}


MLFQ::MLFQ(std::vector<Process>& procs) : processes(procs) {}

void MLFQ::runMLFQ() {
    // Print column headers
    printColumnHeaders();

    // Sorting processes by arrival time
    std::sort(processes.begin(), processes.end(), [](const Process& p1, const Process& p2) {
        return p1.arrivalTime < p2.arrivalTime;
        });

    int currentTime = processes.empty() ? 0 : processes[0].arrivalTime;

    // Create a thread for each process
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (const auto& process : processes) {
        threads.emplace_back([&]() {
            try {
                // Wait until the arrival time
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(process.arrivalTime - currentTime));

                // Update current time
                currentTime = process.arrivalTime;

                // Execute process
                executeProcess(process, currentTime);
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                // Print error message in red
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);
                std::cerr << "\033[1;31mError: " << e.what() << "\033[0m" << std::endl;
            }
            });
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}


//main file
#include <iostream>
#include "MLFQ.h"


int main()
{
    std::vector<Process> processes = {
    Process(1, 0, 10, 1),
    Process(2, 1, 15, 2),
    Process(3, 2, 8, 0),
    Process(4, 3, 12, 1),
    Process(5, 4, 7, 2),
    Process(6, 5, 18, 0),
    Process(7, 6, 5, 1),
    Process(8, 7, 20, 2),
    Process(9, 8, 12, 0),
    Process(10, 9, 6, 1),
    Process(11, 10, 14, 2),
    Process(12, 11, 9, 0),
    Process(13, 12, 16, 1),
    Process(14, 13, 4, 2),
    Process(15, 14, 20, 0),
    Process(16, 15, 8, 1),
    Process(17, 16, 10, 2),
    Process(18, 17, 6, 0),
    Process(19, 18, 18, 1),
    Process(20, 19, 5, 2),
    Process(21, 20, 22, 0),
    Process(22, 21, 9, 1),
    Process(23, 22, 16, 2),
    Process(24, 23, 7, 0),
    Process(25, 24, 12, 1),
    Process(26, 25, 14, 2),
    Process(27, 26, 6, 0),
    Process(28, 27, 20, 1),
    Process(29, 28, 10, 2),
    Process(30, 29, 8, 0)
    };


    MLFQ mlfq(processes);
    mlfq.runMLFQ();

    return 0;
    
}




executeProcess has two prints to cout not guarded by a mutex. Also, where do you position every progress bar on its own line?
